# Action bar not fitting all the items

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Here is my code for my actionbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/actionBarNew"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:title="new" />
    <item android:id="@+id/actionBarSave"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:title="save" />
    <item android:id="@+id/actionBarLoad"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:title="load" />
    <item android:id="@+id/actionBarDelete"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:title="delete" />
</menu>
```

Then in my **onCreate()** method, I add the switch widget like so:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarSwitch, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
        ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.END));
        actionBar.setTitle(title);
        actionBarSwitch.setText(sfx);
        actionBarSwitch.setTextColor(res.getColor(R.color.white));
        actionBarSwitch.setChecked(soundOn);
        actionBarSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

Here is what it looks like at the moment:

[image]

As you can see, the switch widget on the left is covered up. It is supposed to say "SFX" on the left of it but it doesnt fit. Is there any way to keep the icon and all the other action bar icons visible? Maybe scale to fit or something?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Here is my code for my actionbar

I do not believe that `android:scaleType` is a recognized attribute for a `MenuItem`.

> Is there any way to keep the icon and all the other action bar icons visible?

[Use the split action bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar), to move your action bar items (NEW, etc.) to the bottom of the screen on narrow devices.

> Maybe scale to fit or something?

While you are welcome to attempt to use view properties to scale the size of your `Switch`, there is no guarantee that there is enough room to have a usable `Switch` when you're done. You do not have control over scaling of the regular action bar items.

Comment: I don't know if putting the new, save etc buttons at the bottom might be a good idea because they're so close to the thumbs I dont want people accidentally pressing them. Do you think it would be better if those buttons stayed at the top and the switch goes at the bottom? If so, how can I do that, because I have added the switch programmatically.  Thanks for your help by the way :)

Comment: @Clay: "Do you think it would be better if those buttons stayed at the top and the switch goes at the bottom?" -- while you can't do that with the action bar, you are welcome to put the `Switch` somewhere in your main UI.

Comment: Haha, that never occurred to me. I thought because it's a setting, it should go in the action bar. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this is bit of an abuse of the ActionBar.  If you definitely want to fit everything in there, you might try mimicking the ActionBar by adding a LinearLayout at the top of your activity with a background color.  You should be able to use the LayoutWeight parameters to get the widgets to fit then.